# BCrypt. How to store salt with python3?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, bcrypt

We have code, that work for `python 2`.

```
@password.setter
def password(self, value):
    self.salt = bcrypt.gensalt()
    self.passwd = bcrypt.hashpw(value.encode('utf-8'), self.salt)

def check_password(self, value):
    return bcrypt.hashpw(value.encode('utf-8'), self.salt.encode('utf-8')) == self.passwd
```

However, when I try to convert it to python3, we meet following problems:

Error one happens on cassandra driver level:

```
cassandra.cqlengine.ValidationError: passwd <class 'bytes'> is not a string
```

Ok. Casting salt and passwd to string:

```
@password.setter
def password(self, value):
    salt = bcrypt.gensalt()
    self.salt = str(salt)
    self.passwd = str(bcrypt.hashpw(value.encode('utf-8'), salt))
```

Now salt saves. But in `check_password` we get `ValueError: Invalid salt`. 
If we change check password code to:

```
def check_password(self, value):
    return bcrypt.hashpw(value, self.salt) == self.passwd
```

We get error `TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing`.

Where to dig?

**UPD** Salt values in password and check password look same, for example:

```
b'$2b$12$cb03angGsu91KLj7xoh3Zu'                                                                        
b'$2b$12$cb03angGsu91KLj7xoh3Zu'
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Update**

As of version 3.1.0 `bcrypt` provides the convenience function

```
checkpw(password, hashed_password)
```

to perform password checking against a hashed password. This should be used instead of:

```
bcrypt.hashpw(passwd_to_check, hashed_passwd) == hashed_passwd
```

which is shown below. There is still no need to store the hash separately.

---

First of all, you don't need to store the salt because it is part of the hash produced by `bcrypt.hashpw()`. You just need to store the hash. E.g.

```
>>> salt = bcrypt.gensalt()
>>> salt
b'$2b$12$ge7ZjwywBd5r5KG.tcznne'
>>> passwd = b'p@ssw0rd'
>>> hashed_passwd = bcrypt.hashpw(passwd, salt)
b'$2b$12$ge7ZjwywBd5r5KG.tcznnez8pEYcE1QvKshpqh3rrmwNTQIaDWWvO'
>>> hashed_passwd.startswith(salt)
True
```

So you can see that the salt is included in the hash.

You can also use `bcrypt.hashpw()` to check that a password matches a hashed password:

```
>>> passwd_to_check = b'p@ssw0rd'
>>> matched = bcrypt.hashpw(passwd_to_check, hashed_passwd) == hashed_passwd
>>> matched
True
>>> bcrypt.hashpw(b'thewrongpassword', hashed_passwd) == hashed_passwd
False
```

No need to store the salt separately.

---

So you could write the setter like this (Python 3):

```
@password.setter
def password(self, passwd):
    if isinstance(passwd, str):
        passwd = bytes(passwd, 'utf-8')
    self.passwd = str(bcrypt.hashpw(passwd, bcrypt.gensalt()), 'utf8')
```

And the checker like this:

```
def check_password(self, passwd_to_check):
    if isinstance(passwd_to_check, str):
        passwd_to_check = bytes(passwd_to_check, 'utf-8')
    passwd = bytes(self.passwd, 'utf8')
    return bcrypt.hashpw(passwd_to_check, passwd) == passwd
```

Comment: I see. Trouble was, that str converts to string like `"b'$2b$12$8YtRw4YT27XpnpSBVZ9KeOlwKXdFhEMjN1Mqee6ySc7.71D1GHRKe'"`. Instead of str we should use `bcrypt.hashpw(passwd, bcrypt.gensalt()).decode('utf-8')`.

Comment: Why don't you use `bcrypt.checkpw()`? It looks like the actual hash values are variable and not necessarily comparable (although they may be the same on the same run).

Comment: @Shule: thanks for point this out, `checkpw()` was added in [version 3.1.0](https://github.com/pyca/bcrypt/#310). Prior to that, circa the time that this answer was posted, the way to check the password was as shown above. I have updated the original answer to recommend use of the new function. There is no issue with the hash changing, because the salt is stored with the hash. If you generate a different salt then you will get a different hash, but that is a different issue.

Comment: @mhawke You're welcome. So, you can use the encoded `passwd` in place of a salt wherever you need a salt, then (even though while it includes a salt, it's not *just* a salt)? I notice the second argument of `bcrypt.hashpw()` is supposed to be a salt.

Comment: @Shule: The salt is prepended to the calculated hash and the resulting string is returned by `hashpw()`. So the hashed password that is stored contains the salt in the first 29 characters, then the hash. `hashpw()` uses the first 29 characters of the second argument as the salt. It ignores the rest of the argument. Thus the hashed password can be used to provide the salt when verifying the password. Look at the first example that I show in my answer - that demonstrates that the salt comprises the hashed password.

Comment: Great but how to I apply this for storing passwords in my MySql database, should I story the hash value(will I have to generate salt once and keep it permanent foot all other hashings, is this a safe approch) or there is some other way. Also does this do key stretching by default and it  can be done by the kfc new to bcrypt